# php: Remove/show specific link from menu based on page displaying

Tags: php, function

Newb here working on refining a function to deliver a better user experience.

My goal is that if we are not on the index page (home) of the site, i wish to include a link to return to the home page. But if we are on the index page (Home), i don't wish to display the redundant link in the menu. Below is the function I've built, which you can see here 'school.max-o-matic.com'. at the bottom of the right navigation menu is a link that reads '< back' which should not show on the index page but should ideally show on all other pages.

I'd hoped the use of the exclamation point followed by an equal sign would do the trick but it did not.

```
<?php

function makeNav($navItem) {
//created variable - plops in what is called when function used on
//page calling the function itself - this is like the strPromp
    $output = ''; //Variable of 0 length
    foreach ($navItem as $pageLink => $displayedLink) {
        if ($pageLink == THIS_PAGE) {
//url matches page - add active class
            $output .='<li class="active">'
                    . '<a href="' . $pageLink . '">' . $displayedLink . '</a>'
                    . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
        } //PHP_EOL is php line end for all systems
        else {//don't add class
            $output .='<li>'
                    . '<a href="' . $pageLink . '">' . $displayedLink . '</a>'
                    . '</li>';
        }
    }

    if ($pageLink != 'index.php') {//add back button to index page
        $output .='<li>'
                . '<a href="./index.php">< Back</a>'
                . '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    } //PHP_EOL is php line end for all systems

    $output .='<li>'
            . '<a href="#contact">contact</a>'
            . '</li>';
    return $output;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/index.php'){ //process if file is not index file.

}
```

to exclude access to index file.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'index.php') !== false) { //process if file contains text "index.php" in filename.

}
```

//to exclude access to any file with name containing "index.php" file

```
if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != 'index.php'){
 //run on all files that ARE NOT index files in any folders.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vish, this did what i wanted. I did have to remove the exclamation point so that the back link didn't display when the index page was loaded as that is the back we'd be going back too. I was thinking the solution might involve some variation on the 'PHP_SELF' which is a super global i believe, yes? Thank you. I am going to think on this and try to internalize it so i have it in my tool box. Have an awesome day!

Comment: @Chezshire You too have an awesome day.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this by using the `$_SERVER` global variable, which is an array of request information. The key 'SCRIPT_NAME' contains the path to the requested file. The check on this could be:

```
if (basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) != 'index.php') {
```

Comment: the script above will block all index.php

Comment: Depends on where you put it. It was meant to replace `if ($pageLink != 'index.php') {`, which is the line the question is about.